# Is nataral to say "can you do any dances" meaning can you dance any dances?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it natural to ask

> Can you do any dances?

meaning can you dance any dances like the walts, the tango etc. If so, can I use the verb *do* instead of *dance*. For example:

> Let's **do** waltz at the wedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't particularly idiomatic. People *do* sometimes say "*he did a dance*", but "do/did" is a bit odd because "dance" is itself a verb, although it can also be a noun when referring to a specific type of dance.

If you wanted to know if someone can dance in general, it would be more natural to ask:

> Can you dance?

Or, if referring to a *specific* dance or dances, you could ask:

> Do you *know*  any dances?

It would be unusual to ask "can you dance any dances?", but if naming a particular dance it would be idiomatic to ask, for example, "can you dance the Foxtrot?"

Comment: If I ask "do you know any dances" that would mean can you dance any dances? By the way is the question "can you dance any dances?" Is ok?

Comment: As I mentioned in my final paragraph, it would be *unusual* to say "dance a dance", although not incorrect. "Do you know any dances" is how I would idiomatically ask if someone knew *how* to perform a specific dance. Knowledge alone without the practical ability to perform it would mean they know *of* a dance.